# Accessing context API when using inertia.js and code splitting

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-context, code-splitting, inertiajs

I wrote my project in react and now I want to add it to Laravel using inertia.js but I can't access context since I'm using [dynamic-import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) for code splitting.
I'm wondering if there is a way to access context in this situation.
This is my app.js code:

```
    import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react'

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => require(./src/screens/${name}),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        render(<App {...props} />, el)
    },
})
```

Comment: Have u tried Redux?